# Computer crashes, Bluescreen appears just for less than a second, no minidump

Tags: windows-7, bsod

I would like to know if it is possible to get to know why a pc crashed without having a minidump?
My computer crashes sometimes but instead of showing the bluescreen for about 5 seconds while creating a minidump it is just shown for less than a second and then the computer reboots.
Is there a way to find out why the computer crashes?

I am using Win7 x64.
Thanks in advance

Comment: If a system crash dump is not created it points to the storage device itself being the cause of the crash.

Comment: I suggest getting UBCD or Hiren's Boot CD and running the usual test's on your Memory, Hard Disk and CPU. It could also be the power supply, is it whistling?

Comment: thanks to you both. psu is not whistling. i will try your suggestions too Jikag.

Comment: Windows needs a pagefile to create dumps. Make sure the pagefile is configured correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, without seeing the error, it would be difficult to troubleshoot, but what you can do to prevent the computer from rebooting:

1) Click 'Start' 
2) Right-click "Computer" 
3) Choose 'Properties' from the menu 
4) Click 'Advanced System Settings' on the left 
5) On the 'Advanced" tab, click the 'Settings' button under "Startup and Recovery" 
6) Make sure that under the "System failure" section, the following boxes are set appropriately:

a) "Write an event to the system log" is **CHECKED** 
   b) "Automatically restart" is **UN-CHECKED**

7) Click 'Ok' 
8) Click 'Ok' again 
9) If it says you need to reboot, reboot

This will prevent the computer from rebooting when it happens so you can get the details from the BSOD, and it should write it to a log.
Once you have that information, we can look for a specific fix.

Comment: You're welcome, I hope it does too!  :)